# What are some examples of the validate() and reset() methods in Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, struts

cam any one give me the example of validate() and reset() methods in struts2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tutorial that covers the validate method:
http://www.vaannila.com/struts2/validation1Example1.html

Here is a tutorial that uses the reset method:
http://www.rkcole.com/articles/struts/crudTutorial/step1.html

Comment: thanx for giving me ur precious time and answer